# Set title/header in Shiny Dashboard

Tags: r, shiny

I want to set the title of my Shiny dashboard to something reasonable and informative, but I cannot get that working. I know have got

```
tags$title("Dashboarding through the snow")
```

in my `ui.R` (within the `dashboardPage` environment if that makes a difference) and this results in this:

[image: Snapshot of my title]

How can I remove the `<title>` part and just have my text in the header?

Comment: Can't you just set it via `ui <- dashboardPage(title="Browser title",
  dashboardHeader(title = "Basic dashboard"),
  dashboardSidebar(),` You don't need to go through tags

Comment: @user3293236 Yep, that did the trick! You can make it into an answer if you want

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can set the title via:

```
ui <- dashboardPage(title="Browser tab title", 
   dashboardHeader(title = "Dashboard title"), 
   dashboardSidebar()
)
```